# Call modal if the condition is met

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to make the modal show in the condition is met but the problem is no modal is showing, can someone help me about this? The php code is below of the modal code.

here's the php

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("connection.php");
if (isset($_POST['login']))
{
    $stud_no = $_POST["stud_no"];
    $password = $_POST["pword"];
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $stud_no);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $password);
    $select_user = "SELECT * FROM student_accounts WHERE stud_no ='$stud_no' AND password ='$password'";
    $run_user = mysqli_query($con, $select_user);
    $check_user = mysqli_num_rows($run_user);
    if ($check_user > 0)
    {
        $_SESSION['stud_no'] = $stud_no;
        header('location: home.php');
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<script>$("#myModal").modal()</script>';
    }
}

?>
```

here's the modal

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: tried `<script>$("#myModal").modal('show');</script>` ?

Comment: open your console and refresh your browser and check that are you getting any error for that ?

Comment: @RanaGhosh Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at index.php:88

Comment: @Mohammad tried it but no luck not working

Comment: @YukihiraSoma as i thought. you need to to include jQuery library before PHP code run, as well as bootstrap JS.

Comment: @RanaGhosh It worked thanks! :)

Comment: @YukihiraSoma Please upvote the answer and accept the answer if it helped you and for others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to **INCLUDE** `jQuery` library before **PHP** code run, as well as `bootstrap JS`. And see the results, it will worked.

**IF** still not worked use below code to echo your script::

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
    . '$( document ).ready(function() {'
    . '$("#myModal").modal("show");'
    . '});'
    . '</script>';
```

Comment: Can you help me about the black in the bootstrap modal because i cant click the close button, the modal is covering with black background of the modal. I think its because it submits and refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

Replace below line

```
echo '<script>$("#myModal").modal()</script>';
```

with

```
echo '<script>$("#myModal").modal('show')</script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First include JQUERY CDN in the  tags

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

2. if (condition === true) //Strict comparison

   $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#form').modal('show');
   });

   else
   ......

N/B #form is the ID for the modal